# Close out window with PVC pipes

Tags: windows, window-frame

we recently discovered there was a closed-out window that we opened up fully to pass 2 HVAC PVC pipes and 2 freon pipes and now need to close it off. What's the best way to do this? The PVC pipes cannot be taken out as that'll cost me a lot to get the HVAC guys to come do just that. It's currently leaking so wondering if we should just put some foam all around to close out any gaps (quick fix) and put some insulation or hire someone who does masonry to break everything and redo a proper frame

https://imgur.com/a/5WFhrts

Thanks

Comment: Please define, "closed out window"   Was the window removed?  What is leaking?  Where is this all in relation to the outside of the house?  Your question is confusing as to the details of the problem. Please revise and add pics of the outside.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Jn1acCT - There was a window here according to the last owner and he closed it. We put some pipes through it as visible in this new picture. I'm just trying to stop the leak we are seeing when it rains hard

Comment: Use some duct seal (monkey sh!t) around the pipes, on the outside.